# If $x\equiv0\pmod a$ and $x\equiv k\pmod b$, is there a simple expression for $x \pmod {ab}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Suppose I know that for some values $x,a,b$ that
$$
x \equiv 0\pmod a
$$
$$
x \equiv k\pmod b.
$$

Is there a simple expression that I can use to get the value of $x$ $\pmod{ab}$ assuming that $a,b$ are coprime?

I know from prior threads that I can use the [extended euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965159/how-to-calculate-x-mod-a-b-if-x-mod-a-and-x-mod-b-are-known) to find this value, however I wanted to know if the additional information that $x=0\mod a$ can make it so we can get a solution without having to run the algorithm and rather just evaluate some expression

Comment: There might be no solutions or multiple solutions if $a,b$ are not relatively prime.

Comment: So, you know that the answer is $a\times n$ for some $n\in \{0, 1, \cdots, (b-1)\}$, but all that tells you is that you need to solve $n\times a \equiv k\pmod b$, so you are still stick inverting $a\pmod b$.

Comment: If you have $\gcd(a,b)=1,$ thenyou can solve $au\equiv 1\pmod b$ and get $x\equiv  kau\pmod {ab}.$

Comment: In any event, there is an algorithm for solving these sorts of problem, when they are relatively prime, high is covered as the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: By the linked [Easy CRT formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) $\, x\equiv a(k/a\! \bmod b)\,\pmod{\!ab}\ \ $